# Google Calendar API - Adding event to calendar without user interaction php

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

Past few days i have been exploring different ways to add event in google calendar using PHP without any luck.

I was able to add event to logged in user after authentication. But i want to add events to shop manager's google calendar without need to authorize every time.

Is it possible? a simple code snippet will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use long-lived [refresh tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token).

> **A Refresh Token is a special kind of token that is used to
>   authenticate a user without them needing to re-authenticate**. This is
>   primarily useful for mobile applications that are installed on a
>   device.
>
> If you are new to refresh tokens, you can learn more about them in
>   this blog post: [Refresh Tokens: When to Use Them and How They
>   Interact with
>   JWTs](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/).

This is what enables you to access your Facebook Messenger and not
have to log-in everytime.

Check the [Refreshing an access token (offline
 access)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)
 guide for Google APIs. These refresh tokens never expire unless you
 choose to revoke them (log-out).

> Note:  There is currently a limit of 50 refresh tokens per user
>   account per client. If the limit is reached, creating a new token
>   automatically invalidates the oldest token without warning. This limit
>   does not apply to service accounts.